# Laravel 8-Can i add data into form inputs without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I got data from Restapi and These data obtained controller class . I want to insert, update, delete data with buttons on click button. I want to use 4 button in same tab so I need to do them dynamically. Can I do it without using JavaScript ?

my getHost function:

```
public function getHost(){

        $enpoint="api/hosts/getHost";

        $api= new ApiAuthController();
        $url=$api->getUrl();
        $headers=$api->getHeaders();
        $url.=$enpoint;

        $response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->post($url,[
            
            'id'=>"11",
            'hostname'=>"",
            'address'=>"",
            'mail'=>"",
            'web'=>"",
            'owner'=>"",
            'contactperson'=>"",
            'mapinfo'=>"",
            'nimage'=>"",
            'description'=>"",
            'telephone'=>"",
            
             
        ]);

        $decode=json_decode( $response->getBody());
         $response=$decode->responseData;
        $data['hostname']=$response->hostname;
        $data['address']=$response->address;
        $data['mail']=$response->mail;
        $data['web']=$response->web;
        $data['owner']=$response->owner;
        $data['contactperson']=$response->contactperson;
        $data['mapinfo']=$response->mapinfo;
        $data['nimage']=$response->nimage;
        $data['description']=$response->description;
        $data['telephone']=$response->telephone;

      
       

        return view('pages.host',$data);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can, by reloading the page on clicking any of these buttons